# Socket don't save values in list

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, arraylist

I'm new in network developing in Java and I want to create a simple Socket server, that get values from client and collects all of them in ArrayList. I wrote an example code, but in server side it not collecting the strings. This is my server side:

**Server**

```
public class ServerSideSocket extends Thread{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    DataInputStream inData;
    DataOutputStream outData;

    public ServerSideSocket(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected!" );
                inData = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                outData = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                System.out.println(inData.readUTF());

                list.add(inData.readUTF());

                System.out.println("------------ VALUES ---------");
                for (String value: list) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
                System.out.println("------------ END VALUES ---------");

                outData.writeUTF("Message saved!");
                outData.flush();
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    inData.close();
                    outData.close();
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 9999;
        try {
            Thread t = new ServerSideSocket(port);
            t.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and **Client:**

```
public class ClientSideSocket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String serverName = "localhost";
        int port = 9999;
        String line = "";

        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
            Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
            System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream outData = new DataOutputStream(out);
            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream inData = new DataInputStream(in);

            outData.writeUTF("Simple text");
            outData.flush();
            System.out.println("Response from server: " + inData.readUTF());
            System.out.println("You can write more messages!");
            System.out.println();

            client.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you try to read twice from the data stream by calling `inData.readUTF()` method. First call successfully reads data from the stream, but instead of saving result you try to perform another read 2 lines below.
`readUTF()` is blocking method and thus it waits for another portion of data which never comes from the same client. That's why your server hungs forever

What you want to do is to read once and store result into local variable:

```
String res = inData.readUTF();
list.add(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing data once as "Simple Text" which you can read only once.

Where in your code you are first reading it

```
 System.out.println(inData.readUTF());
 list.add(inData.readUTF());
```

Instead of this you should first store it in a String and then use it.

```
 String message = inData.readUTF();
 System.out.println(message);
 list.add(message);
```